# JPA Best Practices

Tags: spring, jpa, dao

I would want to know if it is a good practise to use JpaDaoSupport.
We are using EclipseLink as JPA provider currently and would want to know if it is better to move towards using JpaDaoSupport class.

Could someone point the advantages and disadvantages briefly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JpaDaoSupport` is a convenient way to provide `JpaTemplate` inside your DAO class.

However, `JpaTemplate` is mostly redundant and Spring team recommends not to use it in new projects (use `EntityManager` directly instead).

See [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTemplate.html):

> JpaTemplate mainly exists as a sibling of JdoTemplate and HibernateTemplate, offering the same style for people used to it. For newly started projects, consider adopting the standard JPA style of coding data access objects instead, based on a "shared EntityManager" reference injected via a Spring bean definition or the JPA PersistenceContext annotation.

and Reference Documentation:

- [13.5.2 Implementing DAOs based on plain JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight)

Comment: Could youplease elaborate what do you intend by redundant?

Comment: @cyclecount: I mean that, for example, with `JdbcTemplate` you can eliminate huge amount of boilerplate code, whereas `JpaTemplate` mostly duplicates existing operations of `EntityManager` and therefore doesn't make your code better compared to using `EntityManager` directly.

Comment: I'm not sure I call that quote a "recommendation", though, it's just an option.